# Why does Eigenvalues[matrix I defined] not work?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, syntax

This is the code I have in my mathematica notebook. I want to find the eigenvalues of the matrix I created called Hmatrix as defined below. However when I type Eigenvalues[Hmatrix] I get the Hmatrix back with an extra set of brackets preceded by "Eigenvalues" again. Essentially, I am not getting the eigenvalues of this matrix and I wish to know what sort of syntax I have to use to find the eigenvalues of my Hmatrix.

```
ϵs = -13.6;
ϵso = -29.1;
ϵp = -14.1;
ssσ = -7.20;
spσ = 9.46;

θ = (π - β/2);

Hmatrix := 
 MatrixForm[{{ϵs, 0, ssσ, 
    Cos[θ]*spσ, -Sin[θ]*spσ, 
0}, {0, ϵs, 
ssσ, -Cos[θ]*spσ, -Sin[θ]*spσ, 
0}, {ssσ, ssσ, ϵso, 0, 0, 
0}, {Cos[θ]*spσ, Cos[θ]*spσ, 
0, ϵp, 0, 
0}, {-Sin[θ]*spσ, -Sin[θ]*spσ, 0, 
0, ϵp, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ϵp}}]
```

Comment: `Hmatrix` is not an array of numbers: it is a `MatrixForm` object.  Get rid of `MatrixForm` and try it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `MatrixForm` in your code. This is only to be used for display purposes and should be avoided if one wants to do any calculations with the matrix.

Comment: So I should get rid of MatrixForm and use what's left instead to define my matrix?

Comment: @user17338 exactly